# Are WebServices asynch/synch on .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

I call 30 times a WebService method (asmx) from client:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    WSCustom.Test(i,
        function (res) {
            $("#Results").append(res + "<br />");
        }, 
        function (res) { 
            $("#Results").append(res.get_message() + "<br />"); 
        }
    );
}
```

this is the WebService method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string Test(int i)
{
    DateTime m_oStart = DateTime.Now;
    WebClient m_oClient = new WebClient();

    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        byte[] res = m_oClient.DownloadData("http://www.repubblica.it/");
    }

    return String.Format("TotalSeconds:{0}", new string[] { DateTime.Now.Subtract(m_oStart).TotalSeconds.ToString() });
}
```

what I aspect for are asynch replies.

I mean, I should get immediatly 15 replies (with odd `i` it returns immediatly), and during the time the rest of replies (which requires time for download the page server side).

But in fact, the outpup is different: it process the first call immediatly. Than, it waits the second is completed, than I get some odd `i` replies, and so on.

So it is not asynch at all.

How WebServices manage client calls in .NET? And can I do this whole process asynch?

### EDIT

With `EnableSession = false` this is the result:

```
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:1,514
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:1,857
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:2,143
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:1,88
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:3,178
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:3,562
TotalSeconds:2,095
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:4,221
TotalSeconds:1,749
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:3,717
TotalSeconds:0
TotalSeconds:1,977
TotalSeconds:2,421
TotalSeconds:2,439
TotalSeconds:1,807
TotalSeconds:2,124
```

so it is not a Session fault.

Comment: First off, don't use `DateTime` to measure the runtime of a program; it doesn't have enough precision.  Use `StopWatch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `EnableSession=true` on your webmethod.  This is effectively going to queue calls, as the session object will be locked for each request.

If you are not using session, then you should not enable it.

---

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx:

> In order to provide the exclusivity required by GetItemExclusive, a
>   session state provider must implement a locking mechanism that
>   prevents a given session from being accessed by two or more concurrent
>   requests requiring read/write access to session state. That mechanism
>   ensures the consistency of session state, by preventing concurrent
>   requests from overwriting each other's changes. The locking mechanism
>   must work even if the session state data source is a remote resource
>   shared by several Web servers.

Comment: This was the main problem, but the points raised in Servy's answer are also relevant.  Your browser won't make 15 concurrent requests just like that.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are ultimately trying to do, but you could make a single AJAX call to the server, and have that call queue up your multiple requests using TPL and return once all your requests have responded.  They wouldn't necessarily all run at once, depends on how your threadpool is set up, but would be faster than making 30 requests from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

It is asynchronous, in that the method doesn't block in javascript and instead fires a callback when the operation is completed.

It may or may not be *parallelized*, which is different from being *asynchronous*.

Note that most browsers will attach a limit to the number of concurrent AJAX requests going out.  You certainly won't be able to send out 30 requests all at once.  Generally you'll see just a few, 1-3 or so.  That's why you're generally seeing all of the requests in order, and not all coming back around the same time.

Comment: @markzzz You can use a tool to sniff your own network traffic to see for yourself, if you would like.  Most likely the browser is indicating that it received a request to perform an AJAX query, that doesn't mean it sent out the network request for it right then.

Answer (score 0):

WebService is by threads by defualt.
if you have problems try insert Pool Size=10 or more to the connection string, 
pay attention that if you have one general used object use:

```
 lock (myObjList)
            {
                ...
            }
```